# How can I use Tasks with Firestore onSnapshotListener to chain live updates?

Tags: android, firebase, task, google-cloud-firestore

I'm able to chain Firestore get() commands together using Tasks, but I would like to do the same using Firestore's onSnapshotListener so I can chain realtime updates together.

Here's a sample of the code I use to chain multiple get commends together:

```
Query usersQuery = mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID).collection("users");
Query booksQuery = mDbase.collection("books").whereEqualTo("groupID", groupID);
DocumentReference adminDoc = mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID);

final Task<QuerySnapshot> getUsers = usersQuery.get();
final Task<QuerySnapshot> getBooks = booksQuery.get();
final Task<DocumentSnapshot> getAdmin = adminDoc.get();

Tasks.whenAllSuccess(getUsers, getBooks, getAdmin)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Object>> task) {
                List<User> users = getUsers.getResult().toObjects(User.class);
                List<Book> books = getBooks.getResult().toObjects(Book.class);
                Admin admin = getAdmin.getResult().toObject(Admin.class);

                // ...
            }
        });
```

My goal is the following: "(I) want to consider three separate snapshot listeners as a single "stream" and whenever a event is fired in any of them, (I) want to get an update with the latest value for all three." Quote and sample code provided by Sam Stern in Google Firestore forum.

For my purposes it sounds like that I will need live updates.

Here's my nested snapshot code:

```
firebaseGetUsers.readDataRTUpdate(new FirebaseGetUsers.FirestoreCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(final List<User> users) {
            firebaseGetBooks.readDataRTUpdate(new FirebaseGetBooks.FirestoreCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(final List<Book> books) {
                    firebaseGetThisAdmin.readDataRTUpdate(new FirebaseGetThisAdmin.FirestoreCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCallback(Admin admin) {
                            //processing all code here.
                            //books are empty!!
                            System.out.println("books: " + books.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't really feasible for snapshot listeners.  A task represents a unit of work that eventually complete with a final result or some error.  They're not appropriate for ongoing work or streaming data, since there is never a single, final result.  Instead, you register a listener that gets invoked for each update that only stops at the moment you choose to stop it.  So, whatever you're trying to do, you'll have to write code that manages listeners rather than tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug (and information).  Here's my situation:  I need to be able to download data from two different collections at the same time:  One are users, the other are books.  They are dependent on each other (one to many) so I'll need to get both when I request them.  Currently, I'm recursively calling them (one snapshot listener inside another), but I'm looking for a more elegant/proper coding way to deal with this.  Thoughts?

Comment: You can't make multiple queries at the same time when the results of one depends on the results of another.  What you're describing seems normal to me.

Comment: Sorry, I should be a bit more clear:  The results of books isn't dependent on users as it does have a reference ID of the user whom the book is assigned to.  Rather, I need to be able to download info from both collections at the same time since they both are used together to populate a navDrawer (User1>book1, book2 | User2>book1) etc.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already wrote?  It looks like it's already doing that.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my nesting of the realtime callbacks (they are functioning properly).  I just want to make sure that this is appropriate coding method to deal with this scenario.  Additionally, is this the best approach when it comes to fails?  Obviously, each snapshot listener is nested in the next ones "if success" condition, but is this the best approach?  Sorry, I'm still learning both FIrestore and Android.  Thanks for your time and help Doug.

Comment: FYI: the sample above isn't for realtime listeners, just using it as a base example to see if I could do the same with snapshots..